# Indefinite integral which is not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I would like to know if there exists an indefinite integral which is not differentiable? Is this possible? That is, I want to know if there exists a real function F defined in a interval $[a,b]$ by the equation
$$F(x)=F(a)+\int_a^x f(t) dt $$ where $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is only Riemann integrable, that $F$ is not differentiable of such a function? Could you give an example?

Comment: I would say that it is very unlikely.

Comment: http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FVolterra%2527s_function&ei=E4yiVN-nLoO58gWExYLgDA&usg=AFQjCNFtBThYaoOBPMq2Q9kKzw0pdX6lYw&cad=rja

Comment: @Nilan: That example (the Volterra function) is an example of the "opposite" of what this question is about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus says that $F$ is continuous, and differentiable at every point where $f$ is continuous. So to get an example, you must take $f$ discontinuous. For example, if $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\ge0$, then (with $a=0$) we get $F(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $F(x)=x$ for $x\ge0$, so $F$ is not differentiable at the point $x=0$.

Comment: @VivaanDaga: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: if the integrand is riemann integrable then must the antiderivative exist?

Comment: No, as the counterexample in my answer shows.

Comment: But if it does exist it must be continious on [a,b] and if the integrand is continous on[a,b] then antiderivative  must exist and be differentiable on every point in [a,b] is that correct?

Comment: Yes. If an antiderivative exists, it is (by definition) differentiable, and hence continuous. And your second statement is (or follows from) the FTC.